# JSP output on HTML site (without a changeover)

Tags: java, html, jsp

Whenever I click on a button in my HTML side, I'm switching to my JSP-File (localhost:8080/index.hmtl -> localhost:8080/result.jsp). But my intention is to load the JSP script in the background and put the result of the jsp on my HTML side so i still stay on localhost:8080/index.html. Summarized this is a quick overview of my HTML side:

```
<form action="result.jsp">
Some Input textfield: <input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="button" value="eintragen">
</form>
```

So, is there a special command for this or a easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: Use. Jsp include

Comment: Thanks a lot! It's working! :)

Comment: vote up my comment :)